# Configuring python logging with a config file

Tags: python, logging

Please bear with me while I try to explain my setup.

I have an application structure as follows

1.) MAIN AGENT
2.) SUPPORTING MODULES
3.) Various ClASSES called upon BY MODULES

This is a script that basically sets up my logging currently.

logging_setup.py - 
Through this script I set up a custom format using context filters and other classes. A snippet of it is as follows.

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
  CMDID_cf="IAMTEST1"
  def __init__(self, CMDID1):
    self.CMDID_cf=CMDID1

  def filter(self,record):
    record.CMDID=self.CMDID_cf
    return True

class testFormatter(logging.Formatter):
  def format(self,record):
  record.message=record.getMessage()
  if string.find(self._fmt,"%(asctime)") >= 0:
    record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)

  if threading.currentThread().getName() in cmdidDict:
    record.CMDID=cmdidDict[threading.currentThread().getName()]
  else:
    record.CMDID="Oda_EnvId"
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__

def initLogging(loggername)     
  format=testFormatter(*some format*)
  *other configuration settings*
```

So I basically have two questions both of which I believe can be used by I dont know how to implement them correctly.

1.) I want my MAIN AGENT Logger to have format and other configuration as set up by logging_setup script while I want MODULES to log messages having configuration set from a different Config File. 
So in short is it possible for two modules who are logging to the same file to have different configurations set from two different sources.
P.S. I am using logger.getLogger() call to get logger in each of these modules.

2.) If the above isn't possible (or even if it is) how can i make the config file to includes complex formatting ?? i.e. how can I change the following config file so that it will set up the format in the same way as logging_Setup.py does.

My current config file is :

```
[loggers]
keys=root,testAgent,testModule

[formatters]
keys=generic

[handlers]
keys=fh

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fh

[logger_testAgent]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fh
qualname=testAgent
propagate=0

[logger_testModule]
level=ERROR
handlers=fh
qualname=testAgent.testModule.TEST
propagate=0

[handler_fh]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=generic
maxBytes=1000
args=('spam.log',)


[formatter_generic]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d %(message)s
```

I hope I have tried to make the question clear.
Thanks!!